# How can i get response in from reduce method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I am trying to upload multiple attachments from multiple inputs using `reduce` method. But it returns nothing in response. Can you please help me to fix the issue?

```
const uploadFile = (event: any, type: Number = 1) => {
  const file: File = event.target.files[0]
  files.push(file)
  filesUpload.value = files
}

const save = () => {
if (filesUpload.value) {
    const files = filesUpload.value
    const uploadFiles = (files: any) => {
      return files.reduce((p: any, file: File) => {
        return p.then(() => uploadAttachment(file))
      }, Promise.resolve())
    }
    uploadFiles(files).then((res: any) => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
}
```

```
const uploadAttachment = (attachment: File): Promise<any> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const storageRef = storage.ref(attachment.name).put(attachment);
    storageRef.on(`state_changed`, snapshot => {
      uploadPercentage.value = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
    }, error => {
      reject(error);
    }, () => {
      uploadPercentage.value = 100;
      storageRef.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
        resolve(url);
      }).catch(err => {
        reject(err)
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: perhaps your `uploadAttachment` is rejecting - you have no test for that - if you expect `save` to return anything, you're out of luck too, since there is no `return` from `save` - and finally, `console.log(res);` will only log the result of the LAST `uploadAttachment` call (as long as there's no rejections in the meantime, then that code won't even run)

Comment: not familiar with `storageRef.on` - does it really take 4 arguments? perhaps you can describe what `storage.ref(attachment.name).put(attachment);` is, which "library" that code is using